# Delay between click and function execution with jQuery

Tags: jquery, function

I'm facing a strange problem.

On click on buttons `Yes`or `No`, I'm trying to execute a function to sum value on the items list.

---

This is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/k4b1awgp/

```
$('li.nav-item').click(function() {
    $(this).closest("ul").find('a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).closest("ul").find('i').hide();
    $(this).find("a").addClass("active");
    $(this).find("i").show();
    updateTotal();
});
$('li.nav-item:nth-child(2) .fa-check').css("display","none");
```

---

This is a not working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/ceuL8p1k/

```
$('li.nav-item').click(function() {
    updateTotal();
});

function updateTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    $('a.active').each(function(){
        total += isNaN(parseInt($(this).parent().data('value'))) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).parent().data('value'));
    });
    $('#total').html(total);
}

updateTotal();
```

For this example, it's not working unless I click a second time on `Yes` or `No`.

---

Do you know why ?

Should I need to put a `sleep` similar PHP function ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#events):

> **shown.bs.tab**:  This event fires on tab show after a tab has been shown. Use event.target 
>   and event.relatedTarget to target the active tab and the previous active tab (if available) respectively.

Hence, I suggest to change your click event handler to:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    updateTotal();
});
```

There is no need to add a delay. It's enough to run your function after the toggle happens.

```js
function updateTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    $('a.active').each(function(){
        total += isNaN(parseInt($(this).parent().data('value'))) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).parent().data('value'));
    });
    $('#total').html(total);
}
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    updateTotal();
});
updateTotal();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" >

Total:
<div id="total"></div>

<div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h2>Item 1 - $50</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs-outline">
                <li class="nav-item" data-id="item_1" data-name="Item 1" data-rate="No" data-value="0">
                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#">
                        No
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" data-id="item_1" data-name="Item 1" data-rate="Yes" data-value="50">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#">
                        Yes
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h2>Item 2 - $250</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs-outline">
                <li class="nav-item" data-id="item_2" data-name="Item 2" data-rate="No" data-value="0">
                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#">
                        No
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" data-id="item_2" data-name="Item 2" data-rate="Yes" data-value="250">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#">
                        Yes
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h2>Item 3 - $75</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs-outline">
                <li class="nav-item" data-id="item_3" data-name="Item 3" data-rate="No" data-value="0">
                    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#">
                        No
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" data-id="item_3" data-name="Item 3" data-rate="Yes" data-value="75">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#">
                        Yes
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. Nice suggestion. How can I target more specifically `li.nav-item`? Thanks.

Comment: You don't. It's enough you target the children having the data-toggle attribute and the event **shown.bs.tab** is fired in order to change from active or not.

Comment: Sure, but image I have a `<li class="nav-item" data-id="8">...</a>` between the `<a>` tag. How can I get this `data-id` info now? Thanks.